# is it possible to allow developer to only validate their changeset than deploy?

Tags: apex, deployment, change-set

We gave full access to developer sandbox for developer. Once the development is done, then we allow them to upload changeset to test sandbox. Then they go with request for deploy which takes 3 day based on their work load. Its really mess with developer since if they miss some component or faced validation error then they again upload the updated one and have to wait for the next validation.

Is there any  way to create functionality (APEX) class to trigger only validation and get the result back?

Comment: Have you tried ANT?

Comment: I try to automate this process. create req in object -> Pull chagneset and validate then send email to the owner.

Comment: You can try ANT and as well as force.com IDE for avoiding again and again package upload and deploy.

Comment: the point is to restrict access and try test deploy as admin in hidden way and send the success or error message to the requester.

Comment: You are describing a version of `continuous integration`. There are several ways to accomplish this through the Metadata API, but change sets do not support automation.

Comment: Yeah . Thatway we can upgared the latest code to test. But my concern here is to pick the changeset and validate changeset and send the result back. So I paln in such a wayt that the user create chagneset and upload and create the changeset  info in custom object . Trigger will get the changeset name and [functionality looking for] validate the changeset and store the result back to the object.which trigger the email to send the result back to users.